# gdb doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: debugging, gdb, mingw, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug a 32bit program on Windows 7 (64bit OS) that is using a 32bit dll. I can put a breakpoint through commondline on the source of a relatively medium-sized dll and it works fine and hit the breakpoint, but when I link against a large 32bit dll, the breakpoint does not hit and is ignored. My gdb version is 7.6.1 and configured as mingw32. I would appreciate it if somebody gives me some hint about how to resolve the problem!

Comment: Do you get any warnings from gdb?

Comment: unfortunately no. The breakpoint is set for a dll, thus it's a pending breakpoint and it doesn't get hit.

Comment: How can I get the full log of what debugger does?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html)?

Comment: I have already used this log function. I need something that maybe prints every step and I hope I can get information on why my debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: What does `info breakpoints` say for the ignored breakpoints?

Comment: it shows the breakpoint as pending which is expected since the breakpoint is set inside a shared library and until the library gets loaded, it doesn't know its address.

Comment: And after the library is loaded?

Comment: then it shows the address of the breakpoint in the memory, since it's known at this point. but it never stops at the breakpoint.

Comment: What if you set the breakpoint after the library was loaded, does that change anything?

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately the result didn't change and it still doesn't stop at the breakpoint.